# Audio tag controls doesn't work on Safari browser

Tags: audio, safari, tags, controls

I have an issue about audio tag display on Safari browser. It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. On Safari browser, nothing appears. Link audio source is directed to Amazon S3 file bucket . The name of the file is stored in a PostGresql database, jinja variable (Flask).
Here is my code:

```
<audio style="margin-top:15px;" controls>
     <source src="https://ecnelisflysounds.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/{{liste_db[i][2]}}">
</audio>
```

[Link to the web application soundmap. Audio controls must appear in each popup windows](https://www.ecnelisfly.com/mapfly_en)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing that problem, running the code on windows and the controls attribute works just fine and when i tried to test on macOS 'VM'... the controls didn't appear.

All i did was cloning the project from GitHub into the macOS directly and then ran VSCode on it... deleted the controls attribute and added it again and used the 'GO Live' extension to run it... and it worked [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoIJW.png)

Somehow it was detected when i changed it from the macOS VM itself.